# build array of accessible positions based on Unity 2D tilemap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a multiplayer grid based game in Unity 2D, where the player will be able to move on a path calculated by the game (depending where s/he clicks). Something like HoMM 2 or 3...

Since this will be multiplayer, I want to build a grid (array) of the world where each position will be either 0 (inaccessible) or 1 (accessible). That would be stored on the server. Based on that I would verify if the player can walk the path they requested.

My initial idea was to place bigger objects (like houses, for example) on a tilemap sliced into 32x32px chunks (my tilemap tile size), so I could put "colliding" parts on separate layer than the non-colliding ones. Then I looped through all the tiles in that "collision" tilemap and when tile was found I would mark it as "1" in my grid.

So that worked fine, but I believe it's not the best idea to slice big objects like that and that they should actually be a single sprite, due to performance and ease of use etc...

Please see this post in Unity's forum for screenshots explaining the two approaches:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/best-practices-regarding-cutting-your-sprite-sheets.1444804/

So now to my question :)
How can I check which tiles in a tilemap are actually "occupied" when I go with option 2?
When I place a sprite that is bigger than 1 tile from a tilemap point of view only one tile is populated, when in reality (visually and collider-wise) many more are.

I tried playing with Ray Casting into Tilemap Collider but also no luck... Ideas?

Thank you in advance!